Does be specific mean I can't use the same example for two separate issues?
I thought the main focus of a good question on SO was to be specific. What can I do if I have two separate issues (similar, but definitely different) in the same context?
Specifically in relation to these two questions:

How do I invert an image in GraphicsMagick conjure?
How do I set blend mode of an image in GraphicsMagick Conjure?

And this comment:

How do I invert an image in GraphicsMagick conjure?

Am I supposed to flag this? It doesn't really fit any of the reasons for flagging given, but should 'this comment is annoying' be a reason?

What does the comment being annoying have to do with anything? if it's no longer needed it's no longer needed.

"but should 'this comment is annoying' be a reason" - no

Seems fine to be different questions, but ensure they are focused. That means the content and example should be narrowed down. The larger exposition of what your overall script should do doesn't look necessary in either question. Likewise the example code looks like it could be reduced (blur, multiple image composites don't look necessary).

If we do a diff we can see that your questions are basically identical. That th TL;DR (which is longer than the opening sentence) is identical strongly states they are the same question.

I don't understand what the "TLDR" on the question has to do with the specific questions. E.g. if you ask about the second step out of 6, why include steps 3-6? Having the same TLDR, i.e. the same claimed summary of the question, would indicate you do want the entire workflow covered in both questions.

Looking more closely over your questions, you don't have "two separate issues in the same context". You just have two issues and your personal use-case for them overlaps. Yet generally, it does not matter at all for inverting an image that the result may later on be blurred, blended, merged, and blended again. If you edit each question to only focus on the specific issue at hand, poof, the overlap and any misconception about duplication is gone.

@KevinB just frustration, I couldn't come up with a good reason

@MisterMiyagi the TLDR was there to state that the question could be answered from the above information without reading further. however if more information was needed about the context then there it was past the Too Long Don't Read part

@MisterMiyagi yeah i understand but they would typically require two separate markups I assume one for inverting and the other element for blending which would be handy to know. If someone wanted to know either technique they could find it easier with search? I'll edit the questions after work

A TL;DR goes before the statement that summarises, not in an entirely different sentence after, @yarns . Your questions are formatted to suggest the bullet points are the TL;DR, not the statement at the start of the question. So it should have been something like "TL;DR: from GM Conjure I can't work out how to invert the colors on an image.  I'm trying to ..."

@ThomA i thought TL;DR meant Too Long; Don't Read.. as in stop reading, why would it go before the sentence you want everyone to read, which should be a short summary and not too long?

It's "Too Long; Didn't Read", @yarns .

@yarns TLDR doesn't "stop reading here", it means "[if the post was] too long, [so you] didn't read [it]" here's the abridged version. TL;DR or tl;dr, short for "too long; didn't read", is internet slang often used to introduce a summary of an online post or news article.


What to do if I have two separate issues (similar but definately different) in the same context.

For the first issue, you follow the expected steps to identify exactly what part of that context is relevant to the issue, and then:

Only if you are trying to fix a problem in existing code, show a minimal reproducible example of code which demonstrates the problem (which does not necessarily look anything like your actual code; it is your responsibility to take the answer you get to the question that you ask, and adapt it to your actual code)

If you are trying to find out how to do something, show minimal setup code for where the "something" has to happen - the purpose here is to clearly specify the input for the task - and then also clearly show desired output. We should be able to look at potential answers to the question, try them, and be confident about whether they actually work, following your precise specification, without having to ask for confirmation.


Then, for the second issue, do that all over again. If they are actually separate issues, then you will necessarily post different code each time.
It seems like you've correctly identified that you have a multi-step process that you want to implement, and there are several parts that you don't know how to do, and that you should ask about them separately. That's correct so far. But you should also ask about them one at a time, and try out your code for each step and make sure it works before moving on to the next challenge. And for each of these challenges, you should expect different people to answer who have no reason to care about anything else that's going on in your project.
Keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow are not requests to make your code work. They are exactly what they're labelled as: questions, the answers to which you use in order to do more programming. We don't offer a debugging service (not even a rubber duck) or a help desk or a back-and-forth discussion to hammer out a design. We offer answers.

I agree but at the time I thought it was minimal, the context was to show how I intend to use it to avoid having to add detail because I often get questions asking how I'm going to use the code so this is just the opposite, now nobody wants to answer because it looks like i'm trying to get a specific piece of code working.
